# Displaying log data in latest-first format

Tags: c++, python, logging, ncurses, tail

I like having log data in a last-first form (the same way most blogs and news sites organize their posts).

The languages I'm most comfortable in are C++ and Python: is there a way to output log data either to the screen (stdout) or a file with the most recent entry always being on top?

Or is there perhaps a way of modifying `tail` to show the latest lines in a scrolling-down fashion rather than scrolling-up?

Would this entail needing a windowing system *a la* `ncurses`?

Comment: If your log entries are single lines, just use tac

Comment: @William Pursell, as an external tool, that looks like it has promise .. is there an easy way of doing the same with my own applications without tearing-apart `tac`? Also, does it read from end to front, or front-to-end? Will it continue to update is the file is updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using the tac command you can also do :

```
watch "tac file.log"
```

add the -n option if you want to control the refresh time like this

```
watch -n 0.3 "tac file.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

Terminal and console drivers are designed for displaying output in a top-down matter. You will need to resort to an external display manager (ncurses, an HTML layout engine, etc.) if you want to display output in the other direction.

Comment: do you know of any drivers that will display in a bottom-up form for file writing?

Comment: They're strictly for text output to a display, so your question is meaningless.

Comment: no, my question is distinctly **NOT** "meaningless", Ignacio. If there is a such a driver that will display bottom-up, and shell redirection works, then it *should* write the file from "end to front" (as it were)

Comment: Yes, it is. Even if the file is *displayed* bottom-up, as soon as it is redirected it will be written from beginning to end, because that is how filesystems work.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking for a different fs... do you know of any that would fit that bill?